# how to pass id in url

Tags: php

I am trying to send `id` in url and getting the url like this:

```
edittruck.php?truck_id=%2715%27
```

I need like this :

```
edittruck.php?truck_id=15   Any idea please
```

After that I want to get the `truck_id` in `edittruck.php` page for update.

Comment: %2715%27 is for '15' you are passing value in single quotes

Comment: you are passing : edittruck.php?truck_id='15' remove the sigle quote so it should be edittruck.php?truck_id=15

Comment: yes I have fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you are using single quotes.

i.e.  edittruck.php?truck_id='27'

you can use this,

```
$truck_id = str_replace('%20',' ',$truck_id);
```

now you can pass $truck_id in single quotes also.

For getting $truck_id in your 'edittruck.php' file use,

```
if(isset($_GET['truck_id']))
{
    $truck_id = $_GET['truck_id'];
}
?>
```

or use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding single quotes around query parameters.

Single quote is encoded as `%27`.

Remove single quotes before and after `27`

Comment: Yes you are right .. i have checked and fixed earlier thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your are passing variable in your URL like

`truck_id='15'`

remove single quotes from the URL and you will get

`truck_id=15`

Comment: Most Welcome@ErDeepeshTripathi :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a href="edittruck.php?truck_id='.$truck_id.'">Edit</a>
```

Comment: There's no need for concatenation when interpolation will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$truck_id = 15; ///your truck id here
<a href="edittruck.php?truck_id=<?php echo $truck_id; ?>" >Edit</a>
```

And in edittruck.php

```
<?php 
$truck_id='';
if(isset($_GET['truck_id']))
{
    $truck_id = $_GET['truck_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: it's okay.. @ErDeepeshTripathi, then you can close this question and should appreciate all the answers, if they are helpful for you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much all .. I have no need to replace now ... I got the error on same moment and fixed that

```
<a href="edittruck.php?truck_id=<?php echo$row["truck_id"];?>">Edit</a>
```